# I have some wierd graphical issue

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

Almost two days ago I first tried ubuntu and installed on my laptop (Lenovo B590) for the first time, after the installation I see some graphical issue in normal use (browsing) and in some graphical-heavy games (Minecraft).

1. Fist Example - Minecraft:
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FkUn.png)
2. Second Example - Youtube:
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eNfT.png)
3. Third Example - Site Address Bar:
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxNQs.png)

-> Edit 1:
The output of `sudo lshw -C CPU` is:

```
  *-cpu                     
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1005M @ 1.90GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1005M @ 1.90GHz
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: CPU Socket - U3E1
       size: 1895MHz
       capacity: 1900MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz
       capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
       configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
```

And the output of `sudo lshw -C video` is:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

-> Edit 2:
I tried ubuntu 18.04.5 and it didn't had this bug.

-> Edit 3:
memtest86 4/4 passed without any errors.

-> Edit 4:
The output of `ls -al /boot` is:

```
total 135680
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 iul 24 00:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 iul 23 23:07 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248291 feb  5 11:18 config-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248322 iul 15 16:51 config-5.8.0-63-generic
drwx------  3 root root     4096 ian  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 iul 23 23:51 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 iul 23 23:20 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 53200593 iul 23 23:48 initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54077460 iul 24 00:12 initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 iul 23 23:02 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5515823 feb  5 11:18 System.map-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5534491 iul 15 16:51 System.map-5.8.0-63-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 iul 23 23:20 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9716672 feb  9 21:04 vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  9800288 iul 15 17:06 vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 iul 23 23:20 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
```

Comment: Please explain in words what exactly the issue is.

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Show me the output of `uname -r` and `free -h`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Output of `uname -r` is: 5.8.0-59-generic and the output of `free -h` is:                 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3,7Gi       1,5Gi       1,0Gi       365Mi       1,2Gi       1,6Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi       934Mi       1,1Gi

Comment: What video card? What driver? Boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 DVD/USB and see if the problem is gone. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I booted from live usb and still i see this bug. p.s. I use integrated gpu.

Comment: Has Ubuntu ever run properly on this laptop? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C CPU` and `sudo lshw -C video`.

Comment: @heynnema This is the first time installing ubuntu on this laptop and I edited the outputs of those commands.

Comment: At the password screen, when logging in, click the icon in the lower right corner of the screen, and change "Ubuntu" to "Ubuntu under Xorg". Retest and report back.

Comment: @heynnema I don't see "Ubuntu under Xorg", only "GNOME under Xorg" and still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: See my partial answer. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I tried to edit what you said to do, still I see that bug.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I did it.

Comment: See the new addition to my answer.

Comment: @heynnema I tried what you said and still I see that bug.

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema Done. It passed without any errors.

Comment: I don't know the answer then. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema I found the reason for this bug, I reinstalled ubuntu 20.04 and it did't had this bug, after I updated it, it had. In the GRUB menu I selected Advanced Option and selected -48 kernel and it worked fine.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot`

Comment: @heynnema Done.

Comment: I don't see a -48 kernel in /boot.

Comment: @heynnema 43*, sorry.

Comment: @heynnema and how do I make ubuntu boot by default into 43 kernel.

Comment: @enderr Please see Update #1 in my answer. If my answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

**Wayland**

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.

**/swapfile**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

**GRUB**

To make GRUB remember your last selected boot OS, edit /etc/default/grub and edit/add these lines...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

then do `sudo update-grub`.